# missing gnome-mplayer in fedora 25

Tags: fedora, gnome, mplayer

Recently I've installed Fedora 25 on my new laptop. To my unpleasant surprise I'm not able to find `gnome-mplayer` package in repositories. Not even with RPM Fusion enabled.

Is that some kind of error on either side or native mplayer gui for gnome is no longer supported? MPlayer is my favourite video player and native gnome gui is nice touch making it even more useful.

Answer (score 2):

The package looks like is orphaned/retired : https://admin.rpmfusion.org/pkgdb/package/free/gnome-mplayer/ .

Comment: Do you know what that mean? Nobody just had time to package it or the project got dead? Apparently I am not good at searching such informations.

Comment: Sadly it appears to be the latter case. https://pkgs.rpmfusion.org/cgit/free/gnome-mplayer.git/commit/?id=61ef91bc409e955f84c97492996e3ca0855c3eae

Comment: An alternative that I can recommend is `mpv`. It has most, if not all, functions of mplayer, along with a few new ones.